# How can I debug inbox rules in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Just migrated from Exchange 2010 to Exchange Online.

I notice that some (but not all) of my own inbox rules are now not applied. These rules have `MoveToFolder` as action (so the net result is that the incoming mail stays in INBOX).

The rule works when triggered manually; it is "just" the automatic trigger which does not work.

I recreated the rule, both from Outlook and from OWA, in the hope it was just a consequence of the migration; no change.

I had a look at the trace tools of Exchange Online, but I only found the message tracking tool in EAC which is too coarse for my case.

Is there some way to have more information of what Exchange is doing, to have hints at what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Exchange 365, as far as we handle it, https://outlook.office.com/ecp then down the left there are Mail Flow rules, such as redirecting messages to an absence mailbox.

Our users then use Outlook (installed locally), to then set up folder re-direction rules.

```
 ##Connect to Azure & Office 365 On-line
 Connect-AzureAD
 Connect-MsolService
 $cred = Get-Credential
 $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
 Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

 ##Disconnect From Session
 Remove-PSSession $Session
```

(It is annoying, you have to log on three times, there is a better method for Linux clients).

Comment: Thanks. I went that route, as I said (EAC is the same as /ecp). "Rules" are the domain-global (transport) rules, so they do not apply here. But as I said, there is another option, "Message tracking". Unfortunately it is not fine enough to show the application of inbox rules, much less the reasons why such rules are or not applied.

Comment: @AntoineL - I think you can use Powershell to interrogate and possibly create the rules you want. (See above, script not displaying well in comment.)

Comment: As I wrote, I already recreated the rules twice. Anyway, I tried once more with PowerShell. No change, it does not work any better than Outlook or OWA.

Comment: Personally, I wish we had gone with Office 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Do new rules work normally?
The inbox rule is Outlook rule, based on my knowledge , it cannot trace in Exchange server side, all the action happened in local Outlook clients. You need to troubleshoot on Outlook side as the following steps , of course it may be caused by migration.

Rename or Reset SRS File in MS Outlook
Default location of .srs File – C: >> Users >> admin >> AppData >> Roaming >> Microsoft >> Outlook

Comment: New rule does not work any better than the old ones.
Inbox rules are of two kind, "Server-side" which are processed by the Exchange server and "Client-side" which are processed by Outlook. I am only referring to the first kind, those performed on the Exchange server. So Outlook debugging tools are not of much use.

Comment: I mean that the inbox rules works after the message arrives in mailbox. The 'server side' rule is also working in mailbox not server. I didnt know such tool to trace inbox rule. What about Outlook logging?https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-the-Enable-logging-troubleshooting-option-0fdc446d-d1d4-42c7-bd73-74ffd4034af5 it will log for Inbox autoprocessing.

Comment: Excuse me if I was not clear. I do **not** want to be required to permanently log into desktop Outlook for the rules to perform (as would happen if I had marked them as client-side); I would like the mails to be handled by the inbox rules, on the server, even when I read the mails on my phone, or when I connect into my mailbox with OWA while on the road, or with my IMAP client at my home.

Comment: I know. Only some mailboxes have this issue, you could move them to another database for repairing, if the new rules also cannot work.